# Silicone waterproof treatment on former PU treated tent

Tags: gear, camping, tents

I read the following post and wondered if I could use the same method on a tent that was formerly treated from factory with a polyurethane coat.

[What is the best way to re-waterproof a nylon tarp?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8896/what-is-the-best-way-to-re-waterproof-a-nylon-tarp?rq=1&newreg=74b3b2924bfe439885dba9218a64ba36)

My tent is an old eureka acadia 2 and all but a few small remnants of the coating is gone. It's only ever been used a handful of times, but it hasn't been stored well for the past couple of decades.
No rot, holes, or mildew, but I've washed it and it took all the coating off. I'm considering restoring with gear aid pu coating, but wonder if the silicone/spirits solution would be better.

Would it even work since it's not silnylon?

Comment: What is the tent fabric made of? If it is an old Eureka it very well might be polyester and not nylon. There should be a label somewhere on the tent/bag.

Comment: i bought it in '93, so it could be poly. i will have to look. thanks! otoh, what does it matter to the application at hand?

Comment: i looked and the tent, the fly, nor the bag have a materials tag on them. i must've removed them a long time ago

Answer (score 1):

The article linked in the answer you linked [What is the best way to re-waterproof a nylon tarp?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8896/what-is-the-best-way-to-re-waterproof-a-nylon-tarp) says it won't work as well for tent floors when compared to PU: http://jwbasecamp.com/Articles/Silnylon1/index.html  For the tent uppers and fly canopies, it could work well.

Silicone is good for repelling and shedding water, but not for being an actual water barrier that an intact PU layer would be. Water would weep at much lower pressures when compared to a polyurethane coating (<15% per the article.)